# Feature selection for mixed binary, continuous, and categorical data

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest

I have a dataset including ~100 features to predict a response variable with 9 possible categories. The type of the features can be any of continuous, binary (0/1), or categorical with more than two categories. Does anyone have any suggestion for the **feature selection** algorithm that can help to consider all of these variables together? I have already applied Random Forest, Recursive Feature Elimination, Correlation, MIC, Stability, ... but it seems there is a trick for mixed data and I am not aware of.

Comment: Is the response variable ordinal?  Nominal?  What's the total sample size?  What are the category frequencies for the response?  Have you looked at stability of feature selection methods?  I think you'll be disappointed how seldom the results replicate in another dataset.

Comment: The response variable is not ordinal, just some categories (locations), the total sample size is ~200k, the frequency of categories: (60%, 20%, and the rest 20% altogether). That's correct! The stability column does not look promising, its highest value is 0.14!

Comment: I didn't know that random forest handled nominal Y.